# Is this possible to make the migration to email service of google app transparent to users?

Tags: email, outlook, g-suite

Currently, the web hosting for my company manages everything, including the website, email service and the domain.

I am planning a migration of email service to google app, step by step. I've opened an account in google app for my company's domain and will recreate all email accounts in google app. Then I will ask the web hosting to change the domain record to point to the mx server of google app.

All users in my company already have their outlook/outlook express setup to download emails. If I do the steps mentioned above, is this a must that they need to change the mail server setting in the outlook?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to change server settings for each client.  Incoming and outgoing servers use a Google domain.  For example the IMAP server is, imap.gmail.com and not imap.yourdomain.com.  The SMTP server is smtp.gmail.com instead of smtp.yourdomain.com.

There are a few things to keep in mind.  You may or may not have to make the following changes based on your current provider:

1. Are you currently using POP3 or IMAP?  Apparently new users will automatically have POP3 enabled.  This in contrast to what I experienced for my migration, about 2.5 years ago.  If you are using IMAP you will have to enable it for each user.
2. User accounts for POP3/IMAP will need to be "username@yourdomain.com".  Your current provider may just require "username".
3. Outgoing server will now require SMTP authentication, your current provider may or may not require it.
4. POP3/IMAP connections will require SSL connections.
5. Did you intend on getting all current passwords and setting them within Google Apps?

Google does have some excellent resources on configuring email clients.
http://mail.google.com/support/bin/topic.py?topic=12913

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the user accounts, if they are consistent with the google accounts, I don't think you have to reconfigure the accounts on the clients.

Also, bear in mind that some DNS servers may have cached the records, so some of the mails may still go to the old server.